# Call to undefined method Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\BinaryFileResponse::withHeaders()

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

i was trying to download and this bug came out and i don't how to fix it!

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class XFrameHeaders
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure(\Illuminate\Http\Request): (\Illuminate\Http\Response|\Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse)  $next
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response|\Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse
     */
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
    {
        $response = $next($request);
        $response->withHeaders([
            'X-Frame-Options' => 'DENY',
            'X-XSS-Protection' => '1; mode=block',
            'X-Permitted-Cross-Domain-Policies' => 'master-only',
            'X-Content-Type-Options' => 'nosniff',
            'Referrer-Policy' => 'no-referrer-when-downgrade',
            'Strict-Transport-Security' => 'max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains',
            'Cache-Control' => 'no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0',
            'Pragma' => 'no-cache',
            'Expires' => 'Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT',
        ]);
        return $response;
    }
}
```

this is the code that got pop-up on my screen and don't have the knowledge to fix it!
also the error line is number 20

Comment: `$response` has the Closure type, and method `withHeaders` doesn't exist there. Try changing the parameter type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `withHeaders` does not exist in the response object which is an instance of `Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\BinaryFileResponse`.

To fix this error, you can replace `withHeaders` with `headers->set()` which does not accept an array of headers so you have to set each header in one line.

```
$response->headers->set('X-Frame-Options', 'DENY');
$response->headers->set('X-XSS-Protection', '1; mode=block');
$response->headers->set('X-Permitted-Cross-Domain-Policies', 'master-only');
$response->headers->set('X-Content-Type-Options', 'nosniff');
$response->headers->set('Referrer-Policy', 'no-referrer-when-downgrade');
$response->headers->set('Strict-Transport-Security', 'max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains');
$response->headers->set('Cache-Control', 'no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
$response->headers->set('Pragma', 'no-cache');
$response->headers->set('Expires', 'Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT');
```